# How to store a message from the user in a table storage? (Microsoft Bot Framework SDK4 & C#)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, azure-storage

Im building a bot with the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK4 at the moment.
The Bot itself is based on C#. I want the message written by the user to be entered and stored in my own table storage in Azure.

I have seen this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) where the bot saves the message in a file in the Blob Storage, but I need to implement this with the table storage.

It would be super cool if someone knows or has a simple example how to do this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store Bot's state data in Azure table storage.

**For V3 (Deprecated) :**

```
var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Here in this sample github : https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureTable

Also reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

**For V4 :**

The provider for table storage was removed from the SDK. The below are the currently available ones.

[image]

However, there is an **IStorage** abstraction that would allow you to write your own implementation if that's something you think you need.

Something like this :

https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/73d1d98173a82da84f3795cbdd0d473ca97bef4f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/AzureTableStorage.cs

The above is the last version that existed before it was removed from the SDK.

Comment: @Daniel.. just wanted to drop in and check with you whether the above helped ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Storage Client library in your app and send data to table storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet